# 502 proxy error after 5 minutes of python script execution from express

Tags: python, node.js, express, google-chrome

The python script must take almost 2 hrs to compute. But I am getting 502 proxy error after 5mins in chrome and firefox. This happens even after changing the firefox default response timeout. I have also changed the express timeout to 0(infinity).

```
app.get("/claims", function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  const { spawn } = require("child_process");
  const pyProg = spawn("python",["claims.py"]);
pyProg.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
 return res.send(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.toString())));
  });
});
var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
  console.log("App running on port 8000");
});
server.timeout = 0;
```

[image: Chrome Dev tool]

Comment: Why would you want to serve a page that takes 2 hours to load? Is there no other solution? How would you know if the proces is not just stuck because your first attempt at viewing the page gave you a timeout but the proces is still "active"?

Comment: Python script takes 2 hrs to compute calculations from 100mb csv file. I can see the python claims.py running infinitely on htop command. I killed it and started again. I'm having trouble understanding what is going on.

Comment: So your problem is most likely not with the serving of the page, rather with the computation of the CSV processing. Maybe you should debug that first? I am still tempted to say that you should never have a blocking process that takes a long time to compute get triggered from a webcall, but that is just me.